# adding same item into the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        if (!$scope.addMe) {return;}

            $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);

    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (x) {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        $scope.products.splice(x, 1);
    }
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-cloak ng-controller="myCtrl" class="w3-card-2 w3-margin" style="max-width:400px;">
  <header class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
    <h3>My Shopping List</h3>
  </header>
  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li ng-repeat="x in products" class="w3-padding-16">{{x}}<span ng-click="removeItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="w3-right w3-margin-right">×</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
    <div class="w3-row w3-margin-top">
      <div class="w3-col s10">
        <input placeholder="Add shopping items here" ng-model="addMe" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s2">
        <button ng-click="addItem()" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-green">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="w3-padding-left w3-text-red">{{errortext}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i have seen this code in w3schools my problem is i want to add same product which is already in list if i try to add product which is already in list product doesn't add to list or array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values would definitely get pushed into the array, but `ng-repeat` wont allow duplicates hence, you dont see a change in dom, use  `track by  $index` to allow duplicates

```
ng-repeat="x in products track by $index"
```